# Java - Abstract classes and concrete classes

Tags: java

I'm working on my assignment but I got confused with the abstract classes and concrete classes, and I get error from my program...

Suppose there is an abstract class Person and a concrete subclass Student:

```
abstract class Person{
    private String name;
    public Person(String s){
          name = s;
    }
    public String getName() {
          return name;
    }
    public abstract void doAction(Person other);
}

class Student extends Person{
    public Student(String name){
          super(name);
    }
    public void doAction(Person other){
          System.out.println("This person's name is " + getName());
    }
}
```

Then I implement a main function to test it but I got an error...:

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person;
        Student student;

        person = new Student("Sam");
        student = person;
        student.doAction(person);
    }
}
```

It is said `student = person` receiving an error saying that `"Error: Incompatible types: Person cannot be converted to Student"`. What's wrong with that actually and why...? Does anyone can explain this...?

Comment: Tip: use `getClass()` to see which definition is your instance

Answer (score 6):

A `Student` is a `Person`, but not every `Person` is a `Student`.

If you have a variable of type `Person`, you can't assign its value to a variable of type `Student` because, in general, that might not be safe.

If you are certain that it's definitely a `Student` (e.g. you use an `instanceof` check, or you have reasoned about the code and thus "know"), you can cast the variable; but one of the central ideas on object-oriented programming is that you shouldn't need to care about the specific subclass.

There are two ways round this:

- Assign the `new Student()` to the `Student` variable first, and then assign that value to the `Person` variable:

  ```
  student = new Student("Sam");
  person = student;
  student.doAction(person);
  ```

  This is fine because every `Student` is a `Person`, so a `Person` variable can be assigned the value of a `Student` variable.
- Forgo the `student` variable entirely, since you only need a reference to a `Person` on which to call `doAction`, not specifically a `Student`:

  ```
  person = new Student("Sam");
  person.doAction(person);
  ```

Answer (score 2):

During run-time the `person` variable can refer to instances of `Person` which are not instances of `Student`. Therefore the assignment `student = person;` is not allowed.

You have to check the run-time type of `person` and perform a cast in order for the assignment to work (well, the type check is not mandatory, but recommended, in order to avoid potential `ClassCastException`):

```
if (person instanceof Student)
    student = (Student) person;
```

Comment: I don't think you should bring instanceof into it. That's introducing bad oo style to somebody who is struggling with oop concepts.

Comment: @AndyTurner So you would suggest type casting without checking the type first?

Comment: I would suggest not doing `student = person;` because it is meaningless (and wrong).

Comment: I see... Is it meaning that the object `person` does not belong to the class type `Student` during execution...? But I'm still misunderstood that `person = new Student("Sam");` brings the object `person` to `Student` type...?

Comment: @cwckelvin In your specific code `person` does refer to a `Student` instance in runtime, but the compiler doesn't analyze the code to determine the type of the instance this variable will refer to when the assignment is performed. The compiler only uses the static (compile time) types to determine if an assignment is allowed, and a Person reference cannot be assigned to a Student reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
package taskassignment;

public abstract class Person
{
    public String name;

    public Person(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public abstract String doAction(Person other);
}

public class Student extends Person
{
    public Student(String n)
    {
        super(n);
    }

    @Override
    public String doAction(Person other)
    {
        return "The Person Name is : "+ getName();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Person person = new Student("Sam"); 
    Student student = (Student) person; 
    System.out.println(student.doAction(person));
}
```